# mysql sort before group by

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I think this is the [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140785/mysql-order-before-group-by/5140943#5140943).  However, this query is not solve my issue - I have like this table:

```
+--+-------+-----+
|id|user_id|score|
+--+-------+-----+
|1 |1      |5    |
+--+-------+-----+
|2 |1      |16   |
+--+-------+-----+
|3 |1      |15   |
+--+-------+-----+
```

Query:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (`_scorboard`)
GROUP BY `user_id`
  HAVING `score` = MAX(score)
ORDER BY `score` desc 

result 0 rows
```

Why is it returns 0 records ?

Comment: Is this even executing?  `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` is an odd thing to be doing!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140785/mysql-order-before-group-by/5140943#5140943), such a solution are given by

Comment: I solved it like this, but I do not think it is a correct solution
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(t2.firstname, ' ', t2.lastname) AS fullname 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM _scorboard ORDER BY score DESC) AS t1 
            LEFT JOIN _user_profile AS t2 ON(t1.user_id = t2.user_id) 
            GROUP BY t1.user_id 
            LIMIT 0, 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM SCOREBOARD a
  JOIN (SELECT t.user_id,
               MAX(t.score) AS max_score
          FROM SCOREBOARD t
      GROUP BY t.user_id) b ON b.max_score = a.score
                           AND b.user_id = a.user_id
```

If you want those who have the highest score in the table:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM SCOREBOARD a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.score) AS max_score
          FROM SCOREBOARD t) b ON b.max_score = a.score
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query, MySQL groups by the `user_id` of `1` first, choosing any of the rows that it pleases. The `HAVING` clause then applies to these selected rows. Since the selected row may or may not be the one with the `MAX` value of `score`, the query is returning 0 results.

The correct way to do is:

```
  SELECT _scoreboard.*
    FROM _scoreboard JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(score)
                           FROM _scorboard
                           GROUP BY user_id)
      AS t ON _scoreboard.user_id = t.user_id
          AND _scoreboard.score = t.score
ORDER BY _scoreboard.score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question! This was the solution I learnt something from! :)