# codeigniter : want not first but last row of joined table?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

now my joined table returns the first posts row, i want it to have the last row for each topic

this is my code now

```
$this->db->select('*');
      ->where('disccategory_id', $cat);
       ->from('discussiontopics as topics');
       ->join('discussionposts as posts', 'posts.topic_id = topics.id', 'left');
       ->order_by('posts.id', 'desc');
       ->group_by('topics.id');
```

maybe i can only do it with a select inside the join? but not sure how to do that with Codeigniter's Active Record

Comment: Cant you order it in the opposite way and select the top? Or else go for the bottom?

Comment: $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'asc'); doesn't change the result. i only get one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *,
            topics.id AS topic_id
        FROM discussiontopics as topics
        LEFT JOIN discussionposts as posts
        ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
        ORDER BY posts.id DESC) AS h
GROUP BY topic_id
");
```

If you wonder why yours doesn't work, run a `echo $this->db->last_query();` after runned query, and you'll see how if behaves.

Comment: this is how i solved it   `$query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM discussiontopics as topics
            LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM discussionposts
                  ORDER BY id DESC) AS  selectedposts ON (selectedposts.topic_id = topics.id)
            WHERE topics.disccategory_id = $cat
            GROUP BY topics.id;
        ");`

Comment: when parsing values to `query()`, send them through the second argument as an array. `query(" .. topics.disccategory_id = ? ..", array($cat))` this will save your day against SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should not work, the reason why is that `ORDER BY` is executed **after** grouping, if you write

```
->order_by(...)
->group_by(...)
```

or

```
->group_by(...)
->order_by(...)
```

it doesn't matter, the query will always have `GROUP BY` before `ORDER BY`.

What you are most likely having problems with is discussed here:

[MySQL Order before Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140785/mysql-order-before-group-by)

So I would rather write a query manually using

```
$this->db->query('
    SELECT ...
');
```

Or even get a list of rows (your query without grouping) and only take the first one.

Hope it helps!