# How do you optimize a MySQL query that joins on itself and does a "custom" group by?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query that is starting to become slow as the size of the DB table increases:

```
SELECT  
    t.*, 
    e.TranslatedValue AS EnglishValue
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PropertyKey 
    FROM Translations
) grouper
JOIN Translations t 
    ON t.TranslationId = (
        SELECT TranslationId 
        FROM Translations gt
        WHERE gt.PropertyKey = grouper.PropertyKey 
            AND gt.Locale = 'es' 
            AND gt.Priority = 3
        ORDER BY gt.ModifiedDate DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    )
INNER JOIN Translations e 
    ON t.EnglishTranslationId = e.TranslationId 
ORDER BY t.ReviewerValidated, PropertyKey
```

First, I am selecting everything from Translations, joined with itself to get me the corresponding English value also.

Then, I then want to limit my results to only one per PropertyKey.  This is like a group by except I need to pick a specific record to be the one returned (instead of the way group by just gives me the first one it finds). That is why I have the inner query that just returns one TranslationId.

When I run explain I get the following info:

[image]

Is there a way I can return the same set of results without having to have MySQL use a slower derived table?  Thanks!

> **UPDATE**: I created an SQL Fiddle with a schema and sample data. You can
>   run my query for yourself to see the results it gives. I need to be
>   able to get the same results, hopefully in a faster way. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44eb0/3/0

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the results you want?

Comment: MySQL should complain when you execute the query, since PropertyKey in the `ORDER BY` clause is ambiguous (there are three of them, even if they are equal).

Comment: @newtover - It won't complain because there is only one PropertyKey at that level (the other ones are in sub-queries). If you want to stick a t. in front of it for clarity, that's fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for offering to look at sample data and results. Is there a way to attach files to a SO question? Are there any services like JSFiddle for MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have created an SQL Fiddle with the schema, data, and results I need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44eb0/3/0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the most recent `TranslatedValue` for the given local and priority that matches `PropertyKey` in a record.

If so, the following does what you want, using a single correlated subquery:

```
 select t.*,
        (select t2.TranslatedValue
         from Translations t2
         where t.PropertyKey = t2.PropertyKey and
               t2.Locale = 'es' and
               t2.Priority = 3
         order by t.ModifiedDate desc
         limit 1
        ) as EnglishValue
 from Translations t
 having EnglishValue is not NULL
 ORDER BY t.ReviewerValidated, PropertyKey;
```

(The `having` clause eliminates records with no translation.)

If so, then an index on `Translations(PropertyKey, Locale, Priority, ModifiedDate)` should speed up the query.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, but I'm still not getting what I need. I first had to change you query slightly: t2.Locale = 'es' and t2.Priority = 3 should be changed to t.Locale = 'es' and t.Priority = 3. I also had to add where t2.Locale = 'en' because I was getting all sorts of languages in my EnglishValue field. Now the data is exactly the same as my query, except there are still duplicates on PropertyKey.

Comment: @11101101b . . . Of course there are duplicates on `PropertyKey`.  You are not doing a final grouping.  You can add `group by PropertyKey` if that is the output you want.

Comment: I tried that @Gordon Linoff, but you have to do the Group By before the Having and Order By (which does not give me what I want).

Comment: I created an SQL Fiddle. I modified my question with a link to the Fiddle (allows you to actually run queries against my sample schema and data). I also have a fiddle of me trying to implement your query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44eb0/6/0). As you can see, the results are not the same.