# MySQL : ORDER BY FIELD / GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, optimization

My question is about MySQL optimisation and good practice.

I have to get translated text list with order preference : if I can't find text in english, I want to use french text and if it does not exists, I want to use spanish.

In other words, I have :

```
id  lang text
1   fr   text_FR
1   en   text_EN
1   es   text_ES
2   fr   text_FR2
3   fr   text_FR3
3   es   text_ES3
```

And I want:

```
id  lang text
1   en   text_EN
2   fr   text_FR2
3   fr   text_FR3
```

So I read some topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group?lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140785/mysql-order-before-group-by?lq=1), or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by?rq=1). Ok.
I tried this :

```
SELECT text FROM (
    SELECT id, text 
    FROM translation 
    ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'en', 'fr', 'es')
) tt GROUP BY tt.id;
```

But, when I EXPLAIN this query, I can read :

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED translation NULL    ALL PRIMARY PRIMARY 52      1641        Using filesort
```

So it's not optimized, because of the subquery. Can I avoid this subquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `JOIN`ing on a table by `id` for each language.  You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to allow for null results.  The query will still use temporary/filesort because it has to scan the entire table (you can use a `WHERE` to limit it more), but only for the first table.  Lookups on the joined tables should be quick.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(en.text, fr.text, es.text, any.text)
FROM
  f any
  LEFT JOIN f en ON (any.id = en.id AND en.lang = 'en')
  LEFT JOIN f fr ON (any.id = fr.id AND fr.lang = 'fr')
  LEFT JOIN f es ON (any.id = es.id AND es.lang = 'es')
GROUP BY any.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baafc/1

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `COALESCE`!