# Get the first child of a group in active record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We have a referral program. When a referred user subscribes, the referrer should get a percentage of the amount due on the first invoice.

`referral_ids = (an array of a bunch of user_ids)`

I can get a single invoice per referred user like this:

`invoices = Invoice.where(user_id: referred_user_ids, renewal: false).group(:user_id).pluck(:amount_due)`

However, because the `amount_due` may vary from invoice to invoice, I'd like to know how I can ensure that the record returned from the `GROUP BY` is the first /oldest record within that group. Thanks in advance.

Comment: order by creation-date ?

Comment: order will only order the group. I need the first of each of the `grouped` items. calling order with group will just give you the order of the result. Does that make sense?

Comment: similar to what's happening here but was hoping to simplify / use active record: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140785/mysql-order-before-group-by

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the solution you're hoping for, but perhaps (for business reasons) you should consider adding a new field to your invoices table such as

- referral_fee:boolean (defaults to false)
- referral_fee_percent (defaults to 0)

You could then facilitate multiple commissionable invoices per affiliate, and / support sliding scale commissions

- invoice 1 - 100%
- invoice 2 - 50%
- etc.

It might be worth asking your product manager / CEO if they're interested in this type of functionality before dismissing this idea.

This would make finding commissionable invoices very simple.